# Error in Entry Module not found - in Webpack Config file

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-2, webpack-4

I am trying to setup webpack for ReactJs. I am clueless what is wrong with my Webpack Config File which gives me

> ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src' in
>   'D:\wd\javascript\Projects\reactjs-basics

**CODE IS HERE - Two files "Webpack.config.js " and "Package.json"**

> **Webpack.config.js code is :**

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

var DIST_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname,'dist');
var SRC_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname,'src');

var config = {
    entry: SRC_DIR+'/app/index.js',
    output:{
        path:DIST_DIR+'/app',
        filename:'bundle.js',
        publicPath:'/app/'
    },
    module:{
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js?/,
                include: SRC_DIR,
                use:{
                    loader:'babel-loader',
                    query:{
                        presets:['react','es2015','stage-2']
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    mode: 'development',
    watch: true

}

module.export = config;
```

> **Package.json File is**

```
{
  "name": "reactjs-basics",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": " npm run build",
    "build": "webpack -d && copy src\\app/index.html dist\\index.html && webpack-dev-server --content-base src\\ --inline --hot",
    "build:prod": "webpack -p && cp src\\app/index.html dist\\index.html"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "2015": "0.0.1",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
    "webpack": "^4.29.6",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.2.1"
  }
}
```

**

> for reference, Folder Structure with Webpack config code i have attache an image below

**

[Please Click here for folder structure, code and folder structure is juxtaposed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNt2Q.jpg)

Comment: modify your entry object to `entry: './src/app/index.js'` and test if it works by executing the webpack script

Comment: @divine tested it , it didn't work :(

Comment: can you share git link to your codebase?

Comment: @divine here is my git link https://github.com/avvncor/reactJs-basics

Comment: @divine, it compiled, thank you. **My localhost is not working. It doesn't tell me that "Webpack result is server from app"**

Comment: @divine  ** how to set mode to development or production via runtime parameters**

Comment: check this to set mode via cli https://webpack.js.org/configuration/mode/

Comment: @divine          **what about localhost it is not getting started**

Comment: check my updated answer

Comment: @divine it didn't work, i have update my git you can see and correct from there

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've to modify few things

- In your `webpack.config.js` you have `module.export`. This is incorrect. it has to be `module.exports`
- You're using `babel-core@6.26.3` with `babel-loader@8.0.5`. `babel-loader@8.*` is not compatible with `babel-core@6.*`. You've to use `babel-loader@7`. Uninstall your existing `babel-loader`  using `npm uninstall -D babel-loader` and install `babel-loader@7` using `npm install -D babel-loader@7`

Another thing i noted is, you have specified `mode: 'development'` in your `webpack.config.js`. its better to set `mode to development or production` via runtime parameters

**Update**

Remove `mode` & `watch` from your `webpack.config.js`

```
mode: 'development',
watch: true
```

Update your `package.json` with below details.

**Development mode**
You don't need to set `watch` & `mode` as `webpack-dev-server` will do that for you when you run `npm run dev`

```
"scripts": {
    "webpack": "webpack",
    "dev": "mkdir -p dist && cp ./src/index.html dist/index.html && webpack-dev-server",
    "prod": "mkdir -p dist && cp ./src/index.html dist/index.html && npm run webpack -- --mode production"
}
```

To launch `local server` you need to add below configuration in your `webpack.config.js` . Note the `directory name` to which the `devserver` points to.

```
devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "dist/"),
    port: 9000
},
```

**Production mode** Execute `npm run prod` to build your project in production mode

You can see localhost in working state when your run `npm run dev`.This server is launched by `webpack-dev-server` library.  For `production build` you have to configure your own server

Let me know if this helps

Comment: @AmaanImtiyaz You can see localhost in working state when your run `npm run dev`.this server is launched by `webpack-dev-server` library.  For `production build` you have to configure your own server

Comment: @devine   **it didn't work, i have update my git you can see and correct from there**

Comment: @AmaanImtiyaz i recommend you to delete everything from your `scripts` in `package.json` . then copy the "scripts" code from my answer, then paste it inside your `scripts` in `package.json`. Then execute `npm run dev` . You're using `copy` command instead of  `cp` to `copy` files from one folder to another. Which `OS` are you using?

Comment: @AmaanImtiyaz then try this for testing if your project works fine, later you can make it smooth. manually create `dist` folder inside your project. copy this `scripts` and use it in your project for testing.   "scripts": {
    "webpack": "webpack",
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server",
    "prod": "npm run webpack -- --mode production"
  }

Comment: @AmaanImtiyaz don't forget to move your `index.html` into `dist` folder. you have to find alternative commands to `copy files` and `create directory` in windows

Comment: @AmaanImtiyaz no problem. you can upvote if you want. webpack website has good documentation, you can read it to learn more about it.