# Error in Entry module not found and in webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs, webpack-dev-server, src

I'm new to JavaScript and follow a clear node-tutorial on [Github](https://github.com/verekia/js-stack-from-scratch/tree/master/tutorial). 
But whatever I've tried in all modules, I keep getting this error message when I run yarn dev:wds

```
    ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src' in 'C:\Users\Renate\projects'     
    ERROR in multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./src Module not found: 
    Error: Can't resolve './src'  in 'C:\Users\Renate\projects'  @ multi (webpack)-dev- 
    server/client?http://localhost:8
```

I've tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55557233/error-in-entry-module-not-found-in-webpack-config-file), but reinstalling babel-loader 7 did not solve my problem. I've also tried to re-intall the entire webpack-module, but that did not solve my problem either.

My webpack.config.babel.js file:

```js
// @flow

import path from 'path'
import webpack from 'webpack'

import { WDS_PORT } from './src/shared/config'
import { isProd } from './src/shared/util'

export default {
  entry: [
    'react-hot-loader/patch',
    './src/client',
  ],
  output: {
    filename: 'js/bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/'),
    publicPath: isProd ? '/static/' : `http://localhost:${WDS_PORT}/dist/`,
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.(js|jsx)$/, use: 'babel-loader', exclude: /node_modules/ },
    ],
  },
  devtool: isProd ? false : 'source-map',
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
  },
  devServer: {
    port: WDS_PORT,
    hot: true,
    headers: {
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
  ],
}
```

My babelrc.json file:

```js
{
  "presets": [
    "env",
    "flow",
    "react"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "flow-react-proptypes"
  ]
}
```

My package.json file

```js
{
  "name": "your-project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "start": "yarn dev:start",
    "dev:start": "nodemon -e js,jsx --ignore lib --ignore dist --exec babel-node src/server",
    "dev:wds": "webpack-dev-server --progress",
    "prod:build": "rimraf lib dist && babel src -d lib --ignore .test.js && cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack -p --progress",
    "prod:start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production pm2 start lib/server && pm2 logs",
    "prod:stop": "pm2 delete server",
    "lint": "eslint src webpack.config.babel.js",
    "test": "yarn lint && flow && jest --coverage",
    "precommit": "yarn test",
    "prepush": "yarn test && yarn prod:build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "compression": "^1.7.4",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "immutable": "4.0.0-rc.2",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-hot-loader": "^4.5.3",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.3",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-actions": "^2.6.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.4",
    "@babel/node": "^7.8.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.8.4",
    "@babel/preset-flow": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.8.3",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.3",
    "babel-jest": "^25.1.0",
    "babel-loader": "7",
    "babel-plugin-flow-react-proptypes": "^25.1.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-flow": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.0",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-compat": "^3.5.1",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.18.2",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.18.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "1.7.0",
    "flow-bin": "^0.118.0",
    "husky": "^4.2.1",
    "jest": "^25.1.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.2",
    "pm2": "^4.2.3",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "webpack": "^4.41.6",
    "webpack-babel-env-deps": "^1.6.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.10",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.10.3"
  },
  "type": "module"
}
```

My eslintrc.json file

```js
  
{
  "extends": [
    "airbnb",
    "plugin:flowtype/recommended"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "flowtype",
    "compat"
  ],
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "jest": true
  },
  "rules": {
    "semi": [2, "never"],
    "no-unexpected-multiline": 2,
    "compat/compat": 2,
    "linebreak-style": [2, "windows"]
  },
  "parser": "babel-eslint"
}
```

for reference, please find attached snapshot of my folder structure here.

[image: folder structure]

And if you check this [Github](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/7329) page or [this](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6858), you will see there are more with the same problem, but no solution worked for me so far. Hope you can help me!

**update**

I've also tried the suggestion of Alex (see answer here below), did not work.

```
    ...
    entry: [
       'react-hot-loader/patch',
       path.resolve(__dirname, './src/client')
       ],

    ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked your repo and I solved the webpack issue. the main issue was everytime you imported a jsx file, you need to write the extention as jsx. and also there were some errors inside components so some of the components were not resolved. here is one in button.jsx

```
// type Props = {
//   label: string,
//   handleClick: Function,
// }
```

and also since implementation of many packages changed, bundle.js is giving error. for example for react hot reload package, there is no need to import this :

```
 import { AppContainer } from 'react-hot-loader'
```

check the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-hot-loader).

also many babel packages were old version. so i Installed the new packages. you can check the package.json.

implementation of webpack config was also wrong. in webpack.config.js entry point takes relative path but output point takes absolute path. I organized the webpack.config.js.

this project also implements server-side code but for this, you need another webpack.config.js for dev. and also for server-side rendering, you need to use ReactDOM.hydrate and also there are too many important things that this project did not implement. here is the repo:

[modified repo](https://github.com/yilmazbingo/JavaScript-NodeJS)

Comment: Hi Yilmaz, thank you for this and for taking the time to help me! I've tried it, but unfortunately it gave me the same error still. I've also tried:

         entry: {
    main: ["react-hot-loader/patch",
         path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/client")]
  },

But this did not work either. 
Do you know another solution? 
Thank you, Renate

Comment: Hi Yilmaz, thank you for this new answer. I've changed it, but it still gives me the same error. Is there another way to solve this? Or should I start over completely? Thank you again for all your efforts. Renate

Comment: Hi Renate. give me your github repo. i ll look into.

Comment: here is my [githubrepo](https://github.com/RenatevanKempen/JavaScript-NodeJS)

Comment: Hi Yilmaz, First of all, so grateful that you have taken the time to solve my issue!!
I've updated everything you mentioned (my repo is changed), but got new errors.
First one: telling me that I need to use 'import' and not 'require()', but to solve this I've changed the extension of webpack.config.js to webpack.config.cjs. Than I got another error with again can not resolve ./src? check the [errors here](https://github.com/RenatevanKempen/JavaScript-NodeJS)

Comment: i ll try to look this weekend. I do not have time in weekdays

Answer (score 3):

Just a suggestion: have you tried resolving the problematic path before passing it to webpack? Something along the lines: `path.resolve(__dirname, './src/client')` will convert the path from relative to absolute and often times it helps to quiet various loaders.

```
...
  entry: [
    'react-hot-loader/patch',
    path.resolve(__dirname, './src/client'),
  ],

...
```

Comment: Hi Alex, Thank you, but I've tried this already and did not work. I will update my question indeed, forgot to mention this. Thank you.